# Category where every Morphism is a Mono

Tags: category-theory, terminology, order-theory

Is there a well-known term for a category where, equivalently:

1. every morphism is a monomorphism
2. every slice category is a preorder

?

Comment: I've bumped into the exact same structure in my research.  I did not find suitable/universally accepted terminology.  I had to invent it myself.

Comment: And, what was your term?

Comment: 1. is not equivalent to 2., right? Sure the *skeleton* of each slice is a preorder, but you can have many isomorphic and nonequal fields.

Comment: A preorder seen as a category is usually called _thin_. A category such that each slice has proprerty $P$ is often called a _locally $P$_ category. So maybe a _locally thin category_?

Comment: @FoscoLoregian , preorder is the same as thin except I think for size issues. You might be thinking of poset which is a preorder with anti-symmetry.

Comment: @Pece that is very reasonable, same usage of local as in "locally cartesian closed". If you write it as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are equivalent for a small category $\mathcal{C}$:

- Every morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ is a monomorphism.
- Every slice of $\mathcal{C}$ is a preorder category.
- There exists a surjective discrete fibration $\tilde{\mathcal{C}} \to \mathcal{C}$ where $\tilde{\mathcal{C}}$ is a preorder category.
- The presheaf topos $[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ is an [étendue](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%C3%A9tendue).

So you might call $\mathcal{C}$ an étendue category.
This is similar to how a coherent topos is one that admits a site of definition that is a coherent category.
(And note that *every* topos is a coherent category, so it matters whether "coherent" is being used as a modifier of "category" or "topos"!)

Or you might keep things simple and note that a one-object category has this property if and only if it corresponds to a left-cancellative monoid, so you might call it a [left-cancellative category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/left+cancellative+category).

Answer (score 3):

A category in which there is at most one morphism between two objects is called [thin](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/thin+category). A category for which each slice is a *gizmo* category is often called a *locally guizmo* category (for example [locally cartesian closed category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+cartesian+closed+category)).

Hence it makes sense to call a category in which every morphism is mono a *locally thin* category.

---

Beware though that it is not standard and I wouldn't use it without redefining it first.

Comment: This terminology is very confusing, because locally thin 2-categories are "2-categories in which every hom-category is thin". The two meanings of "locally" conflict here, so I would avoid this terminology.